# Getting value of int[] via reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, int

Okay, so I'm trying to get the value of a `int[]` via reflection, and it's been going poorly. Here's my code:

What I'm trying to get value of

```
public int[] blah;

for(Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
    f.setAccessible(true);
    if(f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("blah")) {
       Logger.write("Name: "+f.getName() +" Value:"+Array.get(f, 1));
    }
}
```

No matter what I do I keep getting "blah is not an array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass a field instead of field value. First, you need to use `f.get(someObject)` to get the actual array from `someObject`, and then call `Array.get` on the resulting object, like this:

```
if(f.getName().toLowerCase().contains("blah")) {
    Object arr = f.get(id);
    System.out.println("Name: "+f.getName() +" Value:"+Array.get(arr, 1));
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/5yoDcM)

Comment: Might want to point out that this assumes `Class c = id.getClass()`

Comment: Thanks for the help :)